# Диалоговые окна в JavaSwing

Tags: java, swing

Как создать диалоговые окна(нужно получить 2 значения типа int) в java с помощью swing?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте JDialog для создания диалоговых окон. На них уже размещаете нужные вам элементы, в которые пользователь вводит значения и получаете свои 2 значения типа int. 
defaultcloseoperation - должен быть suspend_on_close, иначе окно будет закрывать всю программу.